# Use Asp.Net web.config transforms on files other than web.config?

Tags: asp.net, log4net

More specifically I am looking to transform my log4net config XML file so that it has different settings for Production. Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is another way that I could achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can transform other configuration files! Checkout the following link: [Transformations](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)

it requires you to install a package and then your ready to go.